# What will the best databse design be for the following

Tags: database, database-design

I have recently completed my training in programming and wanted some expert advice on what would be best database design for the following:

Client has 50 sites. One head office site:

The sites has the following: Tanks, Equipment.

So I make the Sites the primary file and the tanks and equipment child files.

Then he has suppliers which deliver to the sites. My idea is to create a Supplier database which has relating files for the Order Header, Order Transactions, Delivery Header and Delivery structures.

Now he has customers which are only allowed to utilize some of the sites. But each customer has a company proxy which is allowed to do orders, etc for client. Then he the clients has representatives which is linked to main customer and each one of them can perform transactions on sites they are approved.

Am I on the right route or will this desing be a fail?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> So I make the Sites the primary file and the tanks and equipment child files.

You'll probably make one table for sites, one table for tanks, and one table for equipment.

> Then he has suppliers which deliver to the sites. My idea is to create a Supplier database which has relating files for the Order Header, Order Transactions, Delivery Header and Delivery structures.

You'll probably create a table of suppliers, and tables for orders, order transactions (or maybe line items), and deliveries.

> Now he has customers which are only allowed to utilize some of the sites. But each customer has a company proxy which is allowed to do orders, etc for client. Then he the clients has representatives which is linked to main customer and each one of them can perform transactions on sites they are approved.

A table of customers, a table that shows which customers are allowed to use which sites, a table of customer proxies, a table of client representatives, at least. (It's not clear whether a customer and a client are the same thing.)

Many of theses will involve foreign key references. For example, the table of tanks *might* include a foreign key reference to the table of sites.